# Aplicação - jogando esta mensagem - javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException - not writable on type

Tags: jsf, primefaces, java-ee

Olá.É o seguinte ,não estou conseguindo excluir os campos selecionados,e minha aplicação está jogando a mensagem -

***javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /listarFuncionario.xhtml @29,32 selection="#{controlerBean.funcionarioSelecionados}": Property 'funcionarioSelecionados' not writable on type br.com.grande_recife.controller***

Segue meu bean

```
@ManagedBean
```

public class ControlerBean implements Serializable {

```
private List<Funcionario> funcionarios = this.listarDados();

 Funcionario[]funcionarioSelecionados;    



// private PreparedStatement stmte;

public List<Funcionario> getFuncionarios() {
    return funcionarios;
}

public void setFuncionarios(List<Funcionario> funcionarios) {
    this.funcionarios = funcionarios;
}

public Funcionario[] getFuncionarioSelecionados() {
    return funcionarioSelecionados;
}

public void setFuncionarioSelecionados(Funcionario funcionarioSelecionados) {
    this.funcionarios = (List<Funcionario>) funcionarioSelecionados;
}

public List<Funcionario> listarDados() {

    //gerencia
    String sqq = "select funcionario.cpf , nome, matricula,diretoria,departamento,divisao, cargo "
            + "from funcionario "
            + "left JOIN dadosprofissionais "
            + "ON dadosprofissionais.cpf = funcionario.cpf";

    List<Funcionario> lista = new ArrayList<Funcionario>();

    try {
        Statement tt = Conexao.getConexao().createStatement();
        //PreparedStatement tt = Conexao.getConexao().prepareStatement(sqq);
        //tt.setString(1, sqq);
        ResultSet resul = tt.executeQuery(sqq);

        while (resul.next()) {

            Funcionario funcionario = new Funcionario();
            funcionario.setCpf(resul.getString("cpf"));
            funcionario.setNome(resul.getString("nome"));
            funcionario.setMatricula(resul.getInt("matricula"));
            funcionario.setDiretoria(resul.getString("diretoria"));
            funcionario.setDepartamento(resul.getString("departamento"));
            funcionario.setDivisao(resul.getString("divisao"));
            funcionario.setCargo(resul.getString("cargo"));

            lista.add(funcionario);

        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {

        Logger.getLogger(ControlerBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        //Logger.getAnonymousLogger(ListarBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return lista;
}

public void excluir() {



    DeletarCadastro excluir = new DeletarCadastro();
    //excluir.deletarFuncionario();

    for (Funcionario func : funcionarioSelecionados) {       

           excluir.deletarFuncionario(func);


    }



}

}
```

O que pode ser ??

Comment: postar o arquivo xhtml desse Bean pra ficar melhor de visualizar

Comment: Porque retornar um `array` e não um `List`.

Answer (score 0):

Pesquisei sobre esta mensagem ,e o motivo era o set ,pois esta mensagem faz referência ao tipo para gravar e tal, e se usa através do set.

Então o que estava assim

```
public void setFuncionarioSelecionados(Funcionario funcionarioSelecionados) {
this.funcionarios = (List<Funcionario>) funcionarioSelecionados;
```

}

Coloquei assim ..  e no meu xhtml fiz referencia ao botão excluir usando o tabela @ this.

```
 public void setFuncionarioSelecionados(Funcionario[] funcionarioSelecionados) {
    this.funcionarioSelecionados = funcionarioSelecionados;
}
```